# Skipfish - how to return a report, but only do stuff like SQL Injection, page errors, etc?

Tags: skipfish

I'm trying to make use of this tool, to check for security holes in our websites, 404's, etc:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/skipfish/wikis/SkipfishDoc.wiki

As a test, I'm running it with:

```
 ./skipfish -B .google-analytics.com -B .googleapis.com -r 800000 -M -L -e -m 5 -g 10 -o output_folder8 http://www.ultranerds.co.uk
```

I'm hoping to automate this on a cron, and then email out the output. Is there a way to "auto start" it? I was hoping I could do something like I use to confirm a copy of files (without having to confirm);

```
yes | cp -rf /installer/files_to_copy/* /
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this kinda works:

```
yes | ./skipfish -B .google-analytics.com -B .googleapis.com -r 800000 -M -L -e -m 5 -g 10 -o output_folder8 http://www.ultranerds.co.uk
```

The downside, is that it flashes up like:

[image]

and then:

[image]

...and then back to the other screen. So it makes it a bit hard to track whats going on.